# AWS Glue Job failing with error : "Error Writing Row"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

So, I created an ETL job to put data from S3 bucket to Redshift. Job Steps(transforms):

1. CreateDynamicFrame (reading from S3)
2. ApplyMapping
3. SelectFields
4. ResolveChoice
5. DropNullFields
6. WriteDynamicFrame (writing to Redshift)

Job is running without fail if the input files (gzipped) in S3 bucket are small (~15 Mb). But if any of the file exceeds to ~ 20 Mb, job is failing with error "Error Writing Row" RecordCount: 19xxxxxx RecordData: (< ROW >). Surprisingly, the row is getting inserted manually to Redshift w/o error.
Now this makes me think it must be related to size limit of input files. Is there any specific limit? Also, how can I fix the issue, as I can't manipulate the input files?

Below is the Glue Python script:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, 
[   'TempDir',
    'JOB_NAME'
])

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "raw_data", table_name = "raw_table", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [('col0', 'long', 'zip', 'int'), ('col1', 'string', 'state', 'string'), ('col2', 'string', 'mail_address', 'string'), ("other_columns_mapping")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

selectfields2 = SelectFields.apply(frame = applymapping1, paths = ["zip", "state", "mail_address", "other_column_names"], transformation_ctx = "selectfields2")

resolvechoice3 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = selectfields2, choice = "MATCH_CATALOG", database = "test_db", table_name = "dev_public_staging_table", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice3")

dropnullfields4 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice3, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields4")

datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = resolvechoice4, database = "test_db", table_name = "dev_public_staging_table", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink5")

job.commit()
```

Error Logs:

```
18/08/20 14:56:13 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 16.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 36, ip-172-31-55-211.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 8): org.apache.spark.SparkE
xception: Task failed while writing rows
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.univocity.parsers.common.TextWritingException: Error writing row.
Internal state when error was thrown: recordCount=195778, recordData=[42101, 4941 CHARLES ST, PHILADELPHIA, PA, 19124, 2815, , , 4941 , , CHARLES, ST , , C034, 19960614, 0018 , 0301 , , DE, 23-2-3302-00, , , ROBERT, PENDER, , , , AMELIA SHERRILL, LEWIS, , , , , , PHILADELPHIA, PA, 19124, 2815, , 95 , 90 N 24, , , , , PHILADELPHIA, , , , SURVEY & PLAN MADE JOSEPH C BARNARD ESQUIRE, , , Y, SFR, 19960229, 34900, D, 0.000000, 0.000000, 34900.000000, , , 0.0000, , , 0.000000, , 0.0000, 4941 CHARLES ST, , , 103477, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 1007, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, , 0, @NULL@, @NULL@]
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.throwExceptionAndClose(AbstractWriter.java:916)
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:706)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityGenerator.write(UnivocityGenerator.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.write(CSVFileFormat.scala:139)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:325)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:254)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1371)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:259)
... 8 more
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:861)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.UnivocityGenerator.close(UnivocityGenerator.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.close(CSVFileFormat.scala:141)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.releaseResources(FileFormatWriter.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1380)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current state = FLUSHED, new state = CODING_END
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.throwIllegalStateException(CharsetEncoder.java:992)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:572)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushLeftoverChar(StreamEncoder.java:242)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:301)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWr
iter.java:857)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error closing the output.
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.close(AbstractWriter.java:861)
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.throwExceptionAndClose(AbstractWriter.java:903)
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:811)
at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:704)
... 15 more
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadDigest;
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4169)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4116)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1700)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.PutObjectCall.performCall(PutObjectCall.java:34)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.PutObjectCall.performCall(PutObjectCall.java:9)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.call.AbstractUploadingS3Call.perform(AbstractUploadingS3Call.java:62)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:80)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:176)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.putObject(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:104)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.storeFile(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:165)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.storeFile(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.uploadSinglePart(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:193)
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream.close(MultipartUploadOutputStream.java:393)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:108)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:320)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
at java.io.Output
```

@NULL@ in recordData is because Redshift table has two extra columns than the raw file. Seems MD5 error is due to temp file (part-000x) was not created successfully due to error

Comment: Hi @Sourabh, were you able to figure out the solution for this?
I am stuck in a similar situation